# Javascript To Do list app push to array/local storage

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, local-storage, push

I am trying to be able to add user input into an array. I cannot seem to figure out how to go about accomplishing this. I have spent hours trying to figure out exactly what to do. I also would like to have this "to do list" save to my local storage, I am equally frustrated with trying to figure out both of these issues.

Any advice or guidance on how to add to the array from user input and/or how to put this into local storage would be greatly appreciated. It has taken me quite some time to even get thus far. Thank you for all of your help! Greatly appreciated.

Javascript

```
var theList = [];

function todoList() {
  var item = document.getElementById('todoInput').value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(item);
  var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
      checkbox.type = "checkbox";
      checkbox.name = "name";
      checkbox.value = "value";
  var newItem = document.createElement("li");

  newItem.appendChild(checkbox);
  newItem.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("todoList").appendChild(newItem)

  return clear();
}

function clear() {
  todoInput.value = "";
}

console.log(theList);
```

HTML

```
  <h1>To Do List:<h1>
    <input id="todoInput" type="text">
    <button type="button" onclick="todoList()">Add Item</button>
</form>
<ol id="todoList">
</ol>

<script src="todo.js"></script>
```

Comment: Would you mind using jQuery instead of JavaScript ?

Comment: I have yet to start learning jQuery, but thanks for the post! I will have to muddle through it to makes heads/tails of it, but thank you...it is a great reference point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the newly created list-item, just add `theList.push(item)` to your `todoList()` function.

To save the `var theList = []` array to localStorage use:

```
localStorage.setItem("todoList", JSON.stringify(theList));
```

And use this to retrieve the localStroage object:

```
var storedTodoList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todoList"));
```

See the snippet below:

```html
<h1>To Do List:</h1>

<input id="todoInput" type="text">
<button type="button" onclick="todoList()">Add Item</button>

<ol id="todoList">
</ol>

<script>
  var theList = [];

  function todoList() {

    var item = document.getElementById('todoInput').value;
    var text = document.createTextNode(item);
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.name = "name";
    checkbox.value = "value";
    var newItem = document.createElement("li");

    newItem.appendChild(checkbox);
    newItem.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById("todoList").appendChild(newItem);
    
    theList.push(item); // This adds the item to theList[]
    //localStorage.setItem("todoList", JSON.stringify(theList)); // Set localStorage object
    //var storedTodoList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todoList")); // Get localStorage object

    console.log(theList);
    
    
    return clear();
  }

  function clear() {
    todoInput.value = "";
  }
  
</script>

<!-- <script src="todo.js"></script> -->
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does help a lot, thank you so much. I was putting the push in the wrong place in my external js file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using jQuery the following should be good enough - either way it's not very difficult to convert to JavaScript.

Here is a fiddle with a working to do list - https://jsfiddle.net/makzan/bNQ7u/

```
$('#add-btn').click(function(){
    // get value from #name input
    var val = $('#name').val();
    // append the name to the list
    $('#list').append("<li>" + val + "  <a href='#' class='done-btn'>Done</a> <a href='#' class='cancel-btn'>Cancel Task</a></li>");
    // reset the input field and focus it.
    $('#name').val("").focus();
});

// correct approach
$('.done-btn').live( 'click', function() {
  $(this).parent('li').addClass('done');
});    

$('.cancel-btn').live( 'click', function() {
  $(this).parent('li').fadeOut();
});
```

As you can see, the logic is to simply assign listeners which are handled much simpler in jQuery